# JS Currying a static function

Tags: javascript, class, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, currying

I have a piece of code like the following.

```js
// controller.js
class Controller {
    static easyPost = _post(EasyAuth, EasyValidate, EasyHandle);

    static hardPost = _post(HardAuth, HardValidate, HardHandle);

    static _post(auth, validate, handle) {
        return (req) => {
            if (auth(req) && validate(req))
                handle(req);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Controller;

//controllermapper.js
const Controller = require("./controller");

class ControllerMapper {
    static map(req) {
        switch (req.path) {
            case "/easyPost":
                Controller.easyPost(req);
                break;
            case "/hardPost":
                Controller.hardPost(req);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The thinking behind is that I can create `easyPost` and `hardPost` through currying. Because their over all flow are very similar.

However, when I try to push the code up to Google Cloud Function. It throws an error like

```
> Detailed stack trace: /user_code/controller.js:6
>     static easyPost = _post(EasyAuth, EasyValidate, EasyHandle);
>                     ^
> 
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

---

**EDIT**

I changed my code into

```html
// controller.js
class Controller {
    static easyPost(req) {
        Controller._post(EasyAuth, EasyValidate, EasyHandle)(req);
    }

    static hardPost(req) {
        Controller._post(HardAuth, HardValidate, HardHandle)(req);
    }

    static _post(auth, validate, handle) {
        return (req) => {
            if (auth(req) && validate(req))
                handle(req);
        }
    }
}
```

Can any comment on this if this is a good practice?

Comment: That’s a syntax error. You can’t assign a variable inside a class like that. Are you sure a class is what you want for this?

Comment: If not, what should I use. I am from a Java background, I just wanted some `public static` method, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work at the moment

```
class Controller {
    static _post(auth, validate, handle) {
        return req => {
            if (auth(req) && validate(req)) handle(req);
        };
    }
}
Controller.easyPost = _post(EasyAuth, EasyValidate, EasyHandle);
Controller.hardPost = _post(HardAuth, HardValidate, HardHandle);
```

There is a stage-3 proposal where your code, as written, would work - https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features/

well not quite as written - you'd need to specify `Controller._post` as follows

```
class Controller {
    static _post(auth, validate, handle) {
        return (req) => {
            if (auth(req) && validate(req))
                handle(req);
        }
    }
    static easyPost = Controller._post(EasyAuth, EasyValidate, EasyHandle);
    static hardPost = Controller._post(HardAuth, HardValidate, HardHandle);
}
```

Note: you can enable this in babeljs, but it's at stage-2 in babel

Regarding your updated code - you still have to call `Controller._post` not just `_post`

```
class Controller {
    static easyPost(req) {
        return Controller._post(EasyAuth, EasyValidate, EasyHandle)(req);
    }

    static hardPost(req) {
        return Controller._post(HardAuth, HardValidate, HardHandle)(req);
    }

    static _post(auth, validate, handle) {
        return (req) => {
            if (auth(req) && validate(req))
                handle(req);
        }
    }
}
```

To demonstrate that you MUST use Controller._post, here is a pared down version of your code

```js
class Controller {
    static succeeds(req) {
        return Controller._post()(req);
    }

    static fails(req) {
        return _post()(req);
    }

    static _post() {
        return (req) => {
           return `got ${req}`;
        }
    }
}
console.log(Controller.succeeds('ok'))
console.log(Controller.fails('ok'))
```

---

and finally, a version of the code where you don't have to use `Controller._post`

```
const post = (auth, validate, handle) => (req) => {
    if (auth(req) && validate(req)) {
        handle(req);
    }
};
class Controller {
    static easyPost(req) {
        return post(EasyAuth, EasyValidate, EasyHandle)(req);
    }

    static hardPost(req) {
        return post(HardAuth, HardValidate, HardHandle)(req);
    }

}
module.exports = Controller;
```

now `post` is private too

Though, if I were writing this, I'd simply do

```
const post = (auth, validate, handle) => (req) => {
    if (auth(req) && validate(req)) {
        handle(req);
    }
};
class Controller {
}
Controller.easyPost = post(EasyAuth, EasyValidate, EasyHandle);
Controller.hardPost = post(HardAuth, HardValidate, HardHandle);
module.exports = Controller;
```

or, if this is really all there is to Controller

```
const post = (auth, validate, handle) => (req) => {
    if (auth(req) && validate(req)) {
        handle(req);
    }
};
module.exports = {
    easyPost: post(EasyAuth, EasyValidate, EasyHandle),
    hardPost: post(HardAuth, HardValidate, HardHandle)
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will the detail of your comment later. But I edited my question with my "solution", can you give a quick comment about it as well please? Thank you so very much in advance.

Comment: the updated code is not at going to perform what you want - for one thing `easyPost` and `hardPost` do not return anything in that updated code - and you're still need to be calling `Controller._post` not `_post`

Comment: but when I call `Controller.easyPost(req)` it does go through tho.

Comment: Does it? Are you sure? Check the final, executable, demonstration ... with `Controller._post` and with just `_post` ...

Comment: @Man-KitYau - if you can post a version of your code that doesn't use `Controller._post` but still executes correctly, I'd be very interested (unless you've moved `_post` outside of the class of course

Comment: by the way @Man-KitYau - `Thank you for your comment` - this isn't a **comment** it's an **answer**

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by `Check the final, executable, demonstration`. The `ControllerMapper` is working fine with edited `Controller`

Comment: prove it - show code that works correctly @Man-KitYau - considering a) there's no outer scoped function called `_post` I can't see it working at all - look at the executable snippet in my answer - the cutdown version with a button "Run Code Snippet" - do you see the error?

Comment: You are right, sorry. I was copying ( & modifying) my snippet from my project. I made an mistake. It does need to call `Controller._post(..)`. Thank you so much for the correction.

Comment: All good - I'm rarely wrong (actually, I'm constantly wrong, but don't tell my boss)